# Android date input field formatting

Tags: android, date, input, textfield, date-format

I'm developing a simply app for Android in which users may insert a date (only date, not datetime) in an input field. I set my layout code so:

```
<!-- Input Start Date -->
<EditText android:id="@+id/inputStartDate"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:inputType="date"/>
```

The input field allow me only to insert number separated from a dot. Anyway there is no any formatting restriction for day, month and year. For example I can insert a no-sense date such as "85.2056.569". In addition the user must manually insert the separation dot.

Is possible to automatically set dd-mm--yyyy as default date-format style? In addition is possile to automatically insert the "\" separator?

I already study of implementig this manually creating three different custom input field for d, m and y, but I'd like to know how is possibile to customize the default text-date input field.

Thanks.